# Plumbing problems - bath and dishwasher

Tags: water

In shower, hot water doesn't work (no water at all comes out when handle turned to hot side) yet cold water works well - this is in guest bath.  Hot and cold works at sink in same bath.  Master bath - both works well.  IN kitchen both work, but have started noticing leaks around faucet and sprayer base.  Dishwasher in kitchen has stopped working - sounds like no water coming in dishwasher.  What would cause these issues?  Are they related?

Comment: Need more information. Did you just move in? If not, did these problems all occur at roughly the same time or have they been accumulating?

Comment: Does the dishwasher go through its cycle, just never use any water? If so, check the float, it might be stuck.

Comment: I would say the kitchen sink faucet water leak is unrelated. Is your guest shower faucet a single handle or is there separate hot and cold controls?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a shutoff valve somewhere along the line from your hot water heater and usually at the base of each appliance or fixture. I would first make sure the values near the bath and dishwasher are both on. If not try tracking the lines from your hotwater heater to see if any values are shut off.

The values near the bath may look like this:

[image]

The values along the line look like this:

[image]